# Bootstrap Carousel is not working when I am adding my images in src

Tags: javascript, php, html

Does anyone else encounter this problem? I am using bootstrap carousel and it is not sliding well. but if I inspect element, the carousel will now move. I am not seeing anything wrong in my code because I just followed the bootstrap provided code for carousel.

Here is my code

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="carousel_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body-custom-full" id="result">

              <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('metronic/theme/classic/assets/images/tv_images/horn.png')?>" alt="First slide">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('metronic/theme/classic/assets/images/tv_images/star_background.png')?>" alt="Second slide">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('metronic/theme/classic/assets/images/tv_images/horn.png')?>" alt="Third slide">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                     <img src="<?php echo base_url('metronic/theme/classic/assets/images/tv_images/star_background.png')?>" alt="Fourth slide">
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my javascript

```
    $('#tv_launch_tv_mode_btn').click(function() {
        $('#carousel_modal').modal('show');
        $('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel({
            interval: 3000
        })
    });
```

but if I remove all the src value, it is working fine.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the fact that the image sizes are unknown, until they have loaded. And having the whole thing inside a modal, which is probably set to `display:none` initially, likely only makes them start loading once the modal is shown for the first time.

Comment: i will try to load it on another page instead of modal sir. thank you sir. now that i am thinking it, i think this is caused by the modal.

Comment: Everything looks good. I've checked your code [link](https://codepen.io/rockzzz-aksh/pen/XWbZGWP)